# autoconf: error: possibly undefined macro: AC_LIBOBJ

Tags: autoconf

Given the following autoconf snippet:

```
if test x"$rsync_cv_HAVE_GETADDR_DEFINES" = x"yes" -a x"$ac_cv_type_struct_addrinfo" = x"yes"; then
    # Tru64 UNIX has getaddrinfo() but has it renamed in libc as
    # something else so we must include <netdb.h> to get the
    # redefinition.
    AC_CHECK_FUNCS(getaddrinfo, ,
            [AC_MSG_CHECKING([for getaddrinfo by including <netdb.h>])
            AC_TRY_LINK([#include <sys/types.h>
            #include <sys/socket.h>
            #include <netdb.h>],[getaddrinfo(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);],
                    [AC_MSG_RESULT([yes])
                    AC_DEFINE(HAVE_GETADDRINFO, 1,
                            [Define to 1 if you have the "getaddrinfo" function and required types.])],
                    [AC_MSG_RESULT([no])
                    AC_LIBOBJ([getaddrinfo])])])
else
    AC_LIBOBJ([getaddrinfo])
fi
```

When running either `autoconf` or `autoreconf -fi` in that project, I get the error:

```
configure.ac:529: error: possibly undefined macro: AC_LIBOBJ
```

which points to the first `AC_LIBOBJ` occurrence.

Running the following sequence instead works:

```
aclocal
autoreconf
```

The problem is that in this particular project, the configure-script should be named `configure.sh` (and get called using a wrapper), so I'd have to use this sequence instead:

```
autoconf -o configure.sh
autoreconf
```

which always generates the error above.

This is with `autoconf-2.69` plus I have the following (related) options set:

```
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([subdir-objects tar-ustar foreign])
AC_CONFIG_LIBOBJ_DIR([lib])
```

I will most likely replace that whole detection by the one contained in gnulib at some point in the future, but at the moment I would like to keep it the way it is.

Comment: Why would you name it .sh? That's arbitrary and misleading, since `configure.ac` is not a valid shell script. The problem is that you are telling autoconf what your miss-named configure.ac is, but not telling the same information to aclocal.

Comment: Not configure.ac should be named configure.sh, but the result: instead of a configure script I want/need a configure.sh script.
And the result of autoconf (the configure script itself) is a valid shell script.
But as I wrote, the problem starts earlier, when running `autoreconf -fi` for example.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your description. Why can't you call aclocal/autoconf/automake by hand? I believe you have to tell autoconf the explicit name of the output with "-o", because automake will track its dependency (configure.ac) and re-generate it when needed. Can't you simply make `configure.sh` invoke `configure`?

Comment: Ok, I updated the description. The point of my question is: I would like to know why this error happens. Even putting AC_LIBOBJ([something]) on a separate line somewhere before yields that error and I do not understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem as it seems was the following code earlier in the `configure.ac`:

```
# define the directory for replacement function since AC_LIBOBJ does not
# officially support subdirs and fails with automake
AC_CONFIG_LIBOBJ_DIR([lib])
```

where I should really have used autoconf comment instead:

```
dnl define the directory for replacement function since AC_LIBOBJ does not
dnl officially support subdirs and fails with automake
AC_CONFIG_LIBOBJ_DIR([lib])
```

Answer (score 7):

```
apt-get install pkg-config
```

Solve the problem for me.

Comment: I cannot fathom why this helped me, but it did, even on mingw-w64.

Comment: This fix works on Devuan ceres when building simple-mtpfs.

Answer (score 0):

This often happens because of a different macro expanding in incorrect ways. I'd suggest you two things: use `AS_IF` rather than `if .. then .. else` statements, and avoid multiple nested macros.

Just set a result variable to yes or no, then use a single `AC_MSG_RESULT`; and instead of calling `AC_LIBOBJ` twice, just call it once checking that variable.

Comment: Well, this didn't solve my problem but it pointed me to the right direction.